# The type or namespace name 'IProductRepository' couldn't be found (Missing directive of assembly reference)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I can't add using OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Abstract; in my OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI AppStart > NinjectWeb common.cs files

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>(); 
    }
```

How to add reference in `<IProductRepository>`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your WebUI project
2. Select Add reference
3. Go to Project tab
4. Select Domain project
5. Rebuild

I had this same problem and this cleared it up.